The Number PI - Colombian Sudoku
This is a very special Sudoku, created alongside the table on the right, in honor of the first 18 decimals of the number Pi.   Here's how it works: the dots outside the board on the right indicate how many cells in the corresponding column or row of that board contain precisely the same digit as is to be found in the same cell of the solved Sudoku on the left.
Happy Christmas!


This sudoku can be solved like this:

 


Can you explain what you color coding means?

@quarague Orange/Yellow is undetermined, blue is correct cell value, red is incorrect cell value.
